# Does anyone know if there is a ‘ball-bowl’ merger in Australia?

Tags: vowels, australian-english, mergers

I live in Australia, and I recently had a moment of confusion when talking with someone who had merged the words *ball* and *bowl*. They pronounced it something like /bɔl/. They said fall, small, wall, role, and whole all the same way, but said tall with the (in my speech) normal /oː/.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? Is it new or have I just completely missed it?

Comment: Well, I don't think that anyone has ever confused a Super Ball and a Super Bowl.

Comment: See: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/117637/ball-and-bowl-do-they-really-sound-the-same

Comment: I know a member of SE who has bowl-ball-bull merger.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul What does SE mean here?

Comment: Stack exchange.

Comment: Why do people keep posting questions like this without saying exactly where the speaker is from, where they grew up, if they have any distinctive ethnic background, etc?

Answer (score 1):

According to a paper by [Cox and Palethorpe (2007):](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-the-international-phonetic-association/article/australian-english/8B2DA5419C7F52650AD8107DEC3E47FD)

> Various pre-nasal and pre-lateral vowel effects are common in SAusE. /əʉ/ as in coat [k<sup>h</sup>əʉt] becomes [ɔo] before velarised /l/ (coal [k<sup>h</sup>ɔoɫ]). Therefore, words like dole [dɔoɫ] and doll [dɔɫ] contrast primarily by vowel duration rather than quality.

It's reasonable to assume that your friend has also lost some or all of the difference in vowel duration.

As for why it *doesn't* affect the word *tall* in your friend's speech, that seems like an individual idiosyncrasy.